# How to passing php variable in exec?

Tags: php, variables

I'm trying to pass php variable in exec() but I found there is no output.

**first.php**

```
echo exec('php prog.php $var1 $var2');
```

**second.php**

```
$file = 'people.txt';

$person = $argv;

file_put_contents($file, $argv, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

How can I pass php variable in exec()?

Comment: Try with double quotes `echo exec("php prog.php $var1 $var2");`